# Hover effect from outside menu

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, hover

I have a menu with nice hover effect (http://markilfin.lx10.net/buftemp/)
What I want to do is to have the same effect, but not only when I hover corresponding image, but and when I hovers corresponding word. Is this actually possible?

Comment: You should give all the resources to the question in this site!

Comment: some code in your question please!

Comment: everything is possible. just depends how much bent you are.

Comment: I thought that it is better post a link to mine example(with all mine code) is better than just post my code here.

Answer (score 3):

This is untested, as yet, but I'd suggest:

```
$('.menu a').hover(
    function(){
        var elemText = $(this).text();
        if ($('#' + elemText).length){
            $('#' + elemText).css({'z-index' : '10'}).find('.zoom').stop().animate({width:"342px",height:"342px",left:"-70px",top:"-70px"}, 400);
        }
    },
    function(){
        var elemText = $(this).text();
        if ($('#' + elemText).length){
            $('#' + elemText).css({'z-index' : '0'}).find('.zoom').stop().animate({width:"212px",height:"212px",left:"0",top:"0"}, 400);
        }
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u3qRP/1/).

Though I'd probably revise that suggestion to the following:

```
$('.menu a').hover(
    function(){
        var elemText = $(this).text();
        if ($('#' + elemText).length){
            $('#' + elemText).trigger('mouseover');
        }
    },
    function(){
        var elemText = $(this).text();
        if ($('#' + elemText).length){
            $('#' + elemText).trigger('mouseleave');
        }
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u3qRP/).